# Uploading big files to SkyDrive folder from Windows Phone 8

Tags: file-upload, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, live, onedrive

I'm trying to upload big files to SkyDrive from Windows Phone 8 device.
In order to avoid OurOfMemory exception I have to write file bytes manually (without SDK) to request stream with AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false

```
var putUrl = string.Format("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/{0}/files/{1}?suppress_response_codes=true&suppress_redirects=true&overwrite=true&access_token={2}", _folderId, fileName, _session.AccessToken);
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(putUrl);
webRequest.ContentType = string.Empty;//Empty is required for PUT method.
webRequest.Method = "PUT";
webRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
webRequest.ContentLength = fileStream.Length;
webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(iar =>
{
    using (var requestStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(iar))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[1024*100];
        var read = 0;
        while ((read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) <= buffer.Length)
        {
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, read); //!!!IT HANGS HERE WITHOUT ANY ERROR!!!
            if (read < buffer.Length)
                break;
        }
    }
}, webRequest);
```

It works fine for small and medium files (<50MB) but uploading hangs at requestStream.Write (at different percentage, sometime it is 30%, sometimes 50%) and wouldn't continue execution for large files (100-500 MB).

I appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Alexey Strakh

Comment: You try to download your file with what Type of Connection? 2G/3G/4G/Wifi/Ethernet(USB connected) ? that don't work in wifi too?

Comment: Have you looked into [Background File Transfer](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/26/31-days-of-mango-day-26-background-file-transfer/)?

Comment: @DocRoms same behavior for all connection types: 2g/3g/4g/wifi. Just stuck on different percentage.

Comment: @NeilTurner Yes, there are low limit which are didn't work in my case

Comment: @DreamTeam Mobile: We are facing the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @NeilTurner unfortunately no. There is no solution with skydrive now (at least we didn't find any). You have to implement custom uploader proxy (backend part) which will accept your large file. Then your backend could submit this file to skydrive.